# how to solve error of Libara Library in Omnet?

Tags: ant, clang, omnet++, ant-colony

**I am using**

1. OMNET++ 5.4.1
2. Libara Library Version 1.2
3. clang version 5.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_501/final)
4. Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu

I am interested in the implementation of AntColony Optimization routing for VANET.
After importing  Libara Library : https://github.com/des-testbed/libara

**Error :**
0:58:48 **** Build of configuration clang-debug for project ARA-Simulation ****

make MODE=debug all

Compiling src/core/AbstractARAClient.cpp

clang++.exe: error: unsupported option '-fPIC' for target 'x86_64-w64-windows-gnu'

make: *** [Makefile:309: out/clang++-debug/src/core/AbstractARAClient.o] Error 1

I think there is a flag -fpic in makefile of Libara making the issue.

## Compiler options

CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -fPIC

Help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.